# looping through groupby in Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python. I am trying to write the code on the python dataframe to loop through the data. Below is my initial data:

```
A   B   C   Start Date  End Date
1   2   5   01/01/15    1/31/15
1   2   4   02/01/15    2/28/15
1   2   7   02/25/15    3/15/15
1   2   9   03/11/15    3/30/15
1   2   8   03/14/15    4/5/15
1   2   3   03/31/15    4/10/15
1   2   4   04/05/15    4/27/15
1   2   11  04/15/15    4/20/15
4   5   23  5/6/16      6/6/16
4   5   12  6/10/16     7/10/16
```

I want to create a new column as forward_c. Forward_C is the data of that row which satisfies the conditions:

1. Column A and B should be equal.
2. Start_Date of the row should be greater than Start Date and End Date of the current Row.

The expected output is :

```
A   B   C   Start Date  End Date    Forward_C
1   2   5   01/01/15    1/31/15        4
1   2   4   02/01/15    2/28/15        9
1   2   7   02/25/15    3/15/15        3
1   2   9   03/11/15    3/30/15        3
1   2   8   03/14/15    4/5/15         11
1   2   3   03/31/15    4/10/15        11
1   2   4   04/05/15    4/27/15         0
1   2   11  04/15/15    4/20/15         0
4   5   23  5/6/16      6/6/16         12
4   5   12  6/10/16     7/10/16         0
```

I wrote below code to achieve the same:

```
df = data.groupby(['A','B'], as_index = False).apply(lambda x: 
x.sort_values(['Start Date','End Date'],ascending = True))

for i,j in df.iterrows():

    for index,row in df.iterrows():

        if (j['A'] == row['A']) and (j['B'] == row['B']) and (row['Start Date'] > j['End Date']) and (j['Start Date'] < row['Start Date']):

            j['Forward_C'] = row['C']

            df.loc[i,'Forward_C'] = row['C']

            break
```

I was wondering if there is any more efficient way to do the same in python.
Because now my code will iterate through all the rows for each record. This will slow down the performance, since it will be dealing with more than 10 million records.

Your input is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
RD

Comment: Hi Roopa. You mentioned one of your conditions for forward_c is "Column A and B should be equal." But column A and B are not equal for many rows where you have a value for forward_c in your expected output. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Hi Roopa. You also mention *Start_Date of the row should be greater than Start Date...*. How can a value be greater than itself? Did you mean across different rows?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion created. When I say that column A and column B should be equal. The value of A and B should be equal to the other rows A and B. In my example, first 8 rows are having same values for column A and B. Also I am comparing start date of one row with other row's start date, not by itself. I hope this is clear. Please let me know for more elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

I was not exactly clear with the question. based on my understanding, this is what i could come up with. Iam using Cross Join instead of a loop.

```
import pandas
data = #Actual Data Frame
data['Join'] = "CrossJoinColumn"
df1 = pandas.merge(data,data,how = "left",on = "Join",suffixes = ["","_2"])
df1 = df1[(df1['A'] == df1['A_2']) & (df1['B'] == df1['B_2']) & (df1['Start Date'] < df1['Start Date_2']) & (df1['End Date'] < df1['Start Date_2'])].groupby(by =['A','B','C','Start Date','End Date']).first().reset_index()[['A','B','C','Start Date','End Date','C_2']]
df1 = pandas.merge(data,df1,how = "left",on = ['A','B','C','Start Date','End Date'])
```